# elasticsearch change number of shards / replicas

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to change the number of shards and replicas for an index as shown below.. 
I am using ElasticSearch 2.4.0.

I did reindex the data and trying to change the number of shards and replicas with the new index.

For example if I want to reindex the bank data (screenshow below) - with 3 shards and 1 replica - how would I proceed?

[image]

Query:

```
 curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/newbank -d'{ "settings": {
    "number_of_shards":2,
    "number_of_replicas":1
    }}'
```

Error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"already exists","index":"newbank"}],"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"already exists","index":"newbank"},"status":400}
```

Saw a similar kindof exception msg in elastic forum as well - which i have come across as well : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-2-1-1-no-of-shard-settings/37825

Getting this error:

```
{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "can't change the number of shards for an index"
}
],
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "can't change the number of shards for an index"
},
"status": 400
```

Kindly help!

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You need to delete the `newbank` index first, you cannot create a second index with the same name.

Comment: my first index name was bank, reindexed one is newbank. should I delete bank one?

Comment: The error is as clear as it gets: "index newbank already exists"

Comment: run `curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/newbank` first and then you can try again

Comment: how did you reindex ? you have to define setting when creating index

Comment: @val - how would I change the number of shards and replicas? I am facing the another issue : {
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "can't change the number of shards for an index"
}
],

Comment: You can only specify `number_of_shards` when creating a brand new index, if you call that on an existing index, it will not work.

Comment: curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/twitter/_bulk?pretty' @shakespeare.json -d '{"settings":{
"index":{
"number_of_shards":2,
"number_of_replicas":1
}                     
}
}'

Getting this error:     "type" : "json_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Unexpected character ('&' (code 38)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@5307f567; line: 1, column: 2]"
  },
  "status" : 500